# How to turn off automatic syntax checking in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse in Linux and I need to turn off automatic syntax checking and parsing of a any type of text file (java, xml, javascript) while I am editing. I want Eclipse to check for syntax/errors in file ONLY when I click the save button. This problem is becoming very annoying as it slows down Eclipse while I am typing and many times it freezes Eclipse for several seconds and sometimes almost a minute so I cant get anything done on time.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck `Project > Build automatically`

But I would do differently. I will make a fresh installation of Eclipse and see if the issue persists. If your machine is good enough (mine is 2x2.2ghz, 2gb ram) you should not have any problems with eclipse.

Comment: I have already unchecked Build automatically as this menu is very visible but it did not make any difference. While I am typing it still checking for syntax/errors. My machine is core 2 duo Dell 4 GB RAM and usually lot of programs running but still CPU is not 100% busy. and memory is used around 50% to 80%.

Comment: @Alan McCloud then you have a problematic installation. Don't sacrifice productivity by disabling these extras. Fix your instalation.

Comment: Actually I did that also when I re-installed Eclipse new version (3.6) in a different location. This did not fix the problem.

Comment: Are you talking about syntax checking and not spell checking, right? The spell checking always slows down Eclipse for me. I don't find that a super useful feature and just disabled it.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question. Eclipse's parser can be very slow, especially for large files. "you should not have any problems with eclipse" the OP's question centers around the fact that they are having problems with eclipse.